# Implementing Note Sharing with Nestjs, MongoDB, React Native, and React

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-native, nestjs

I have a note-taking app, and I want users to be able to share their notes with other users or the public. I want the shared note link to display my app's icon, the title of the note shared, and a brief description of the note. How do I implement this logic on the backend with Nestjs and MongoDB? The frontend uses React Native for mobile and React for the web.